Node gives me as version: v23.0.0-nightly2024071586415e4688
I am trying to update node on UBUNTU (version 22.04.4 LTS) and have followed the official procedure on their site:
# installs nvm (Node Version Manager)
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
# download and install Node.js (you may need to restart the terminal)
nvm install 21
# verifies the right Node.js version is in the environment
node -v # should print `v21.7.3`
# verifies the right NPM version is in the environment
npm -v # should print `10.5.0`

At first everything seemed OK, giving me the exact versions of both node and npm. But after closing and reopening the terminal it gives me the version of node: v23.0.0-nightly2024071586415e4688 and as npm version says:
npm warn cli npm v10.8.2 does not support Node.js v23.0.0-nightly2024071586415e4688. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
10.8.2

How can such a thing happen if I have copied and pasted exactly the commands the official website says to use???
How can I solve it? I've tried deleting and repeating the same procedure but I get the same result as above, I've tried restarting the pc and repeating with a newer version but nothing, and I've tried the same with an older version...I always get the same problem!

You may get better responses over on either Ask Ubuntu or [unix.se].

Personally, I've found https://volta.sh much more reliable than nvm

This question is similar to: Node Version Manager install - nvm command not found. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Seems like the initialization of nvm is not correctly inserted in your .bashrc (or whatever shell your are acutally using). I bet when you type nvm in your newly opened terminal you get a "command not found" error. And that node@23 you have on your system is probably not installed by nvm. Try using which node to see where the binary is located

I finally solved it with nvm alias default 21.7.3 and then with nvm use 21.7.3.
It seems to work

Step 1: Install nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash

Step 2: Load nvm into the current shell session
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

Step 3: Install Node.js version 21
nvm install 21

Step 4: Verify the installation
node -v  // Should print the installed Node.js version, e.g., v21.7.3
npm -v   // Should print the installed npm version, e.g., 10.5.0

